# my UPS Software keeps disconnecting and stop communicating with my UPS

Tags: windows-10, usb

im running a Server on my windows 10 PC which is connecting to ups in case of power failure

i also installed the Software that came with my UPS and updated to the latest version to shut down my PC in case of power failure i even reinstalled it several times

the problem is every 5 or 6 days the software will disconnect and stop communicating with the UPS Itself the tray icon will change to gray from yellow

and the only fix is to Restart windows the software will work again for 5 to 8 days then i need to restart windows 10 again but why ?

the UPS is connected to my PC via a usb cable
Windows 10 pro
i5 3570k
gigabyte Motherboard
16 gb of ram
im using this PC as a server running 24/7

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable?  Do you have another UPS compatible with the software?  The problem might be an early indication the UPS is starting to fail.

Comment: this server is running 24/7 since 2 years and i have this proplem since i started using it 24/7 as a server so i dont think it still starting to fail after 2 years i think windows is disconnecting it for some reason maybe ? i have no idea

Comment: I am sure either the software or Windows logs an event when the device disconnects.  Have you check those logs and or events?  Have you tried a different cable?  You made no mention of this being an old problem, that's relevant, changes any potential answer significantly.

Comment: do you have please any idea what i need or where in event viewer i need to search to find what exactly happened ? and i also tried a different cable

Comment: i have USB selective suspend setting in power option enabled maybe i need to disable it ? but as far as i know the UPS is always monitoring so it's not idling for windows to disconnect it ?

Comment: When a USB device disconnects that event is logged.

Comment: Which UPS and which software?

Comment: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71bhL-Kx6%2BL._AC_SL1500_.jpg connected to usb port 2 and the software is this one https://www.power-software-download.com/viewpower.html just to notice that in generic usb hub power management is set to allow the computer  turn off this device to save power can this be my problem ?

Comment: the UPS is this one https://advice.co.il/en/collections/interactive-sine-ups/products/smart-vision-ups-system